# Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name error no matter what url I try to visit

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login

I am trying to reuse an `account` app(manages signup/login/registration using class-based views) I created in one project, in another project.

`account/urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'account'
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name = 'login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name = 'logout'),
    path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name = 'password_change'),
    path('password_change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name = 'password_change_done'),
    # reset password urls:
    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name = 'password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name = 'password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name = 'password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name = 'password_reset_complete'),

]
```

If I try to access any of those URLs, the error will be the following:

```
NoReverseMatch at /account/<url>/
Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
In template /Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/website/templates/base.html, error at line 12
```

The only line that changes is the  `NoReverseMatch at /account/<url>/`.

I do not mention the login view in my very primitive base.html, so I am not sure where that is coming from (file at `project_root/templates/base.html`):

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Website</title>


   {% block head %}

   {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
  {% block content %}

  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Other files I think may be important:
`project_root/urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # user account related urls:
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),

]
```

and somethings I added to `settings.py`:
changed `DIRS` in the `TEMPLATES` variable, so that Django could find my `base.html` file

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and I also added:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login' 
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

I was trying to reuse this functionality as it was working in a previous project, but I feel like I am missing a step somewhere. Any help is much appreciated.

edit: I realized there is also a host of `account` template files that this error could possibly be coming from?

Full stack trace error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/logout/

Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Version: 3.6.1
Installed Applications:
['account.apps.AccountConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/website/templates/base.html, error at line 0
   Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
   1 : 
   2 :     {% load static %}
   3 :     <!DOCTYPE html>
   4 :     <html lang="en">
   5 : 
   6 :     <head>
   7 :       <title>Website</title>
   8 : 
   9 : 
   10 :        {% block head %}


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 443, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/justinobrien/Desktop/recipeSite/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /account/logout/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Comment: Try reversing `account.login`?

Comment: @pkqxdd do you mean `LOGIN_URL = 'account.login' ` ?

Comment: Does the error point to the line with `</head>` in your template? In that case, i suspect that might be an issue with a conflicted namespace or something in the context processor.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of your error?

Comment: @pkqxdd just appended it to the question. Thanks for taking the time to look through it.

Comment: That's a bizarre error. The stack trace you posted says error at line 0, which is before the start of the template. This seems to be an error of a middleware or context processor. I suggest you to either attach a debugger and see why exactly it's trying to reverse `login`, or try to change the name of the view to something else.

Comment: @pkqxdd I have never attached a debugger so definitely going to try and take the time to learn how to do that. Thanks anyway, good to know someone more experienced thinks it's bizarre, I was lost.

Answer (score 2):

Save time and try to avoid changing the default location if you want to use `auth_views`, and that is why you see an error. The answer here is for the login form, you should remove the others logout and etc for now...

> ```
> path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name = 'login'),
> ```

When you used `path('login/',...)`, `LoginView()` gets confused since `LoginView()` already has a default location, have a look at the `template_name` in the [LoginView() class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L45)

```
template_name = 'registration/login.html'
```

The default location is `registration`, if you want to change that you could face changing more directories...

You should add a `login.html` file  into a new `registration` directory in the project `templates` directory, so in your case, you would have `project_root/templates/registration/login.html`, and then use this in the login html file as an example

```
<h1>Log In</h1>
<form method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">log in</button>
</form>
```

[`as_p()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#as-p) to display the look of the form contents. And then change `LOGIN_URL = 'login'` in `settings.py` to [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) it would look like this

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Create a `home.html` next to the `base.html` and add

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<h1>home</h1>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Hey {{ user.username }}!
{% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'login' %}">log in</a>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

in the `project_root/urls.py`, use the django’s built-in `auth` app

```
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

[More info about `auth` app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views)

Import [AbstractUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser) and create a `CustomUser` model  in your `account` app

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Update the `settings.py` file and add an `AUTH_USER_MODEL` config to refer to model `'account.CustomUser'`

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.CustomUser'
```